# Global keybindings to commands or shell scripts in i3

Tags: command-line, unity, bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys

In i3 volume control is not handled by fn Right or Left arrow key. I currently have to put the following in a terminal: `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+(or-)` Which i do by way of an alias vup/vdown. Is there a way to globally bind a command say f1/f2 to an amixer command like the above code snippet? It would have to work even if I was currently in a browser or other non terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for fixing the audio problem at [How to manage audio with i3?](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/2wbv8x/question_how_to_manage_audio_with_i3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have media keys, then paste this at the end of your i3 config file found at `/etc/i3/config` and restart i3 with <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

```
# Pulse Audio controls
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 
+5% #increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume 0 
-5% #decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 0 toggle # 
mute sound

# Sreen brightness controls
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen 
brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen 
brightness

# Touchpad controls
bindsym XF86TouchpadToggle exec /some/path/toggletouchpad.sh # toggle 
touchpad

# Media player controls
bindsym XF86AudioPlay exec playerctl play
bindsym XF86AudioPause exec playerctl pause
bindsym XF86AudioNext exec playerctl next
bindsym XF86AudioPrev exec playerctl previous
```